# reputation recalc on un-downvoted and deleted answers

Tags: support

I downvoted 2 answers. One was deleted and the other was edited so I removed my downvote. I then ran a 'trigger reputation recalculation' however I didn't get any reputation back. Shouldn't you get rep back if you un-downvote someone after they edit their answer, or delete their answer because it was wrong and then manually trigger a reputation recalc?

When I logged off yesterday I had **3,531** when I logged on this morning I had **3,531** After my 2 downvotes I now have **3,529**. However, my reputation history doesn't seem to match

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

I looked at the CodeIgniter Cookies, article (had to do a search for it word for word as there wasn't a link for it. And I have never voted, nor answered that question...

Comment: Double-check your reputation tab (make sure you have `show removed posts` checked). Perhaps you were downvoted or something was deleted.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I did this, but now I just have more questions lol.

Comment: You probably suggested an edit for that post. You gained 2 points for that when the edit was accepted, but now lost the 2 points because the question was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters AHHHH yes, good observation, I forgot you used to get +2 for suggested edits.

Comment: The [suggested edit in question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/436513).

Comment: @MartijnPieters how did you find that?

Comment: @Bot: Users with 10k reputation or more can see deleted answers.

Comment: @Bot: I searched for the literal title of the question, found the deleted answer, looked at the editing history and found the 'suggested' link on the accepted edit. As a 10k+ rep user I can see all deleted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a downvote is undone or an answer you downvoted is deleted, you'll get the reputation back automatically. Triggering a recalc is no longer necessary.

It might take a while to get the rep back when a post is deleted. Rep changes due to undoing votes are instant.

Regarding your edits:

The +1 removed cancelled the -1 when you downvoted the answer.

The -2 could mean that you earned +2 for an approved suggested an edit on an answer that now has been deleted.

Assuming it happened yesterday, the 0 rep change on October 29 is related to the undone downvote. If you undo a downvote the same day you cast it, both changes disappear from your reputation history.

Comment: I lost -1 rep for each downvote, When the answer was deleted, +1 was not awarded back, and when the other was edited and the downvote was taken away, another +1 was not given back. Because of this I triggered a recalc. I am still down -2 rep.

Comment: Us mortals cannot see rep changes due to downvotes. Could you post a screenshot of the relevant parts your reputation page?

Comment: @Bot Don't look at the total reputation; any number of things could have happened over time to add/remove rep for any number of unrelated reasons.  Look at the actual reputation tab with 'show removed posts' checked to see what every entry has.  Also, don't be overly impatient.  Thanks to caching, etc. things can take a bit of time to work their way through the system.  If all else fails, it's two rep, not worth your time to fuss over.

Comment: @Dennis screenshot has been added. I am starting to think something is wrong with my rep, since I received a -2 on a question I have never voted on, nor answered.

Comment: @Bot: Replied in answer.

Comment: @Dennis shouldn't that -2 show in my /reputation for 2 days ago? Why this morning did I have 3,531 when /reputation said I should have had 3,529 as of the 26th? I know it is only 2 points but I am just trying to make sure there isn't a bigger issue here.

Comment: Since recalcs are no longer required, the `/reputation` page is obsolete. It calculated things a little differently (removing events rather than cancelling them out).

Comment: Bad choice of words. I meant a suggested edit that has been *approved*.

Comment: @Dennis per your answer, I see the removed answer was cancelled out however, you state the removal of a downvote should of been instant. Why this morning did it say I had 3,531 but now I only have 3,529 after only doing 1 downvote (the second was cancelled out when the post was deleted)

Comment: I never lost reputation from a suggested edit, so I have no idea how long it takes. I suppose it's possible that the -2 affected your reputation today (although it's displayed as a change from 2 days ago).

Comment: Dennis, I think that is the culprit, I still sometimes need to run a recalc manually for my rep to update sometimes, after a post is deleted. I am betting that running the recalc, took into effect the -2. However it seems I am still out 1 point. :P, oh well. I just thought I would post something here so that if anyone else runs into something like this, it is logged, so that the devs can research it, incase it becomes a problem.

Comment: nvm, I'm not out -1 rep. My rep is correct. The -1 +1 probably won't show because it was an un-downvote. So the recalc just seems to have taken into effect the -2 for the deleted suggested edit.. Thanks for helping me understand guys.

Comment: Some rep changes (e.g., from post deletions) take a couple of hours. If you wait long enough, you don't have to recalc your reputation manually.